# Access folder on drive shared between Windows 10 and Elementary OS

Tags: linux, windows, windows-10, mount, hibernate

### Setup

SSD 1: Windows 10

SSD 2:

- Partition A: Elementary OS (EOS)
- Partition B: "DATA", formated as exFAT

### Problem

I use DATA for some work related stuff under EOS. Worked like a charm. Logged into Windows, accessed DATA from there. Now I have an issue under EOS: via file-explorer I can mount DATA and see the stored folders, but all folders are displayed empty. The volume shows the free storage correctly. When using bash, DATA is mounted under `/media/joba2ca/DATA`  and I can access the folders. But when I `ls` in `/media/joba2ca/DATA/workfolder`, I get an error that "folder '.' is currently being accessed: I/O error" (translated from German). There is another non-work folder on DATA, `/media/joba2ca/DATA/nonworkfolder`, that I can access without any issues. I would like to access the work-related data again.

### Troubleshooting so far

Seems to be related to Windows 10 hibernation stuff and not properly unmounting. Therefore I...

- "unshared" one of the folders under Windows 10 that I previously shared while troubleshooting (don't judge me)
- changed W10 energy options to disable fastboot and hibernation
- unmounted drive via (a) disk management tool (b) command line with `mountvol D: /P` (D: was mountpoint of DATA)

Comment: Have you installed in EOS the packages `exfat-fuse` and `exfat-utils`?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Yes, I have them installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an unexpected, because simple, solution:

1. Under Windows 10, access `/media/joba2ca/DATA/workfolder`
2. Move all contents into `/media/joba2ca/DATA/`
3. `rd /workfolder`. Does not work, because "folder is corrupted" and because Windows
4. Log into Elementary OS
5. `rm -r /workfolder`
6. Solved